# Hosted jquery, ssl on IE9

Tags: jquery, ssl, internet-explorer-9

I am using hosted jQuery for an SSL-enabled site. In IE it's showing this message:

> This webpage contains content that will not be delivered using a secure HTTPS.

If I click "ok", I can use jQuery; if I click "no", I cannot.

When I checked the hosted link for jQuery, it starts with "http".

1. Is there an "https" hosted jQuery as an alternative?
2. Is it a security risk if I clicked "ok"?
3. Is there any method to suppress this message?

Comment: What is the url of the hosted jquery used?

Comment: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">

Comment: If you're using Google's CDN or something similar the // at the start of the link should select the proper protocol based on the request, but you can force it by doing `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has a SSL enabled CDN which hosts jQuery 
[https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js) or https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js

[jQuery Download Page](http://jquery.com/download/) has information regarding different cdns which hosts jQuery. It says both [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) and [Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx) has hosted jQuery with SSL support.